# Going back to default settings in RCy3

Tags: r, cytoscape

I wonder how do you get to default settings with RCy3, after using functions such as, for instance:

```r
setNodeColorMapping()
setEdgeLineWidthMapping()
```

Do I need to name them, then put them under mappings in a visual style, and finally remove the visual style if not happy about it?

Thanks!

David R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I poked around for a bit, but I wasn't able to figure out a way to clear the visual mapping either.  I'm assuming you would just overwrite it, or switch to a different visual style...

Comment: Thanks a lot Scooter. Yeah, that is what I figured out too. It'd be great to be able to do so, though.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended practice is to not edit the "Default" style, but rather copy it (or start from scratch) and edit a custom style (using "style.name"). Then you can switch back to "Default" or any number of styles you create at a later point.